# Variable expansion in target dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile (GNU) where I want to use variables in target dependencies.  For eg.

```
DATE:=$$(date +%Y%m%d)

build: dist/index-$(DATE).js
```

where the above line is expected to check for a file `index-20190920.js` in the dist folder.  The above variable expansion doesn't work and I get an error `no rule to make target dist/index-$(date needed by build`

I tried `$$` to escape the variable and and also other directives like `SECONDEXPANSION` and `SECONDARYEXPANSION`.

What is the right way to use a variable in target dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do but... if you want the variable `DATE` to represent the current date in the specified format then just use...

```
DATE := $(shell date +%Y%m%d)
```

Comment: The build artifact is a file with datestamp on the file name.  For eg. The second line should expand to `build: dist/index-20190920.js`